# Add customView below navigationBar Title

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to add a custom view below the navigationBar title, such that navigation bar preserves the default translucent effect and also adjust its height to accommodate the custom view?

Apple is doing it in Health App, App Store Connect App and Also in Calendar App.

[image: Navigation bar in Apple Apps]

I have gone through the Sample Provided by Apple:
[Customizing Your App’s Navigation Bar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/customizing_your_app_s_navigation_bar).
but it doesn't provide any help.

Found an archived sample code: [NavBar: Customizing UINavigationBar's appearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html)
It has a sample image which shows that a label is added below the title and is also a part of navigationBar but after running the sample project I checked that there is no way to even replicate that.

According to an answer to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583741/uisegmentedcontrol-on-navigationbar-below-title):
Adding custom view as title view and setting the prompt text doesn't give ability to change the prompt text font which looks weird.

Comment: This isn't possible with default navigation bar. You have to create custom navigation bar view and hide default.